# Azure Policy Naming Convention

Tags: azure-policy

I have this JSON script, which allows me to force the addition of "bi" or "dfy" followed by 3 letters for the name of a resource group.

And I would like to add the possibility of adding several characters afterwards. I have tested with the character * but it does not work.

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
      },
      {
        "field": "name",
        "notMatchInsensitively": "bi..."
      },
      {
        "field": "name",
        "notMatchInsensitively": "dfy..."
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

You can use below **JSON** to block the **Resource Group** creation if field is not match.

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
},
{
"not": {
"anyOf": [
{
"field": "name",
"like": "bi-"
},
{
"field": "name",
"like": "dfy_"
}
]
}
}
]
},
"then": {
"effect": "deny"
}
},
"parameters": {}
}
```

> Note: Resource group names can only include alphanumeric, underscore, parentheses, hyphen, period (except at end), and Unicode characters that match the allowed characters.

Policy will accept the resource creation if rule is match.

[image]

Policy is denying **Resource Group** creation if I enter another name as below.

[image]